# Baking a Scala Cake with shared types

Tags: scala

I'm trying to build a very general solver system. My goal is to make it easy to mixin different problem spaces (graph coloring, knapsack packing, etc.) with various abstract solvers (branch-and-bound, local search), and various concrete strategies (like the specific "goodness" function). I can sort of make it work with generics, but it's hard to pull together all the configuration into one place. My theory is that a cake and abstract types would be better here.

Consider a Baker who wants to make a cake.

```
val ingredients: Set[Ingredient] = shopper.shop
val cake: Cake = baker.bake(ingredients)
shipper.ship(cake)
```

`Ingredient` and `Cake` are unknown types, and could be absolutely anything. What we do know is that  shop() returns ingredients, bake() will convert them to a cake, and ship() will accept that cake. I'm trying to do it like this (I'm not certain that I'm using self-types correctly):

```
override def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val shopper = new IntShopper
  val baker = new IntBaker

  val ingredients = shopper.shop
  val cake = baker.bake(ingredients)
  ...
}

trait Bakery {
  type Cake
  type Ingredient
  type Recipe <: bakery.Recipe
}

trait IntBakery extends Bakery {
  override type Recipe = SummingRecipe
  override type Ingredient = Int
  override type Cake = Long
}

trait Shopper {
  self: Bakery =>
  def shop: Set[Ingredient]
}

class IntShopper extends Shopper {
  self: IntBakery =>
  override def shop: Set[Ingredient] = Set(1,2,3)
}

trait Recipe {
  self: Bakery =>
  def combine(is: Set[Ingredient]): Cake
}

trait Baker {
  self: IntBakery =>
  def bake(ingredients: Set[Ingredient]): Cake = (new Recipe).combine(ingredients)
}

[...]
```

This is where it breaks down. There are multiple path-dependent versions of `Ingredient`, and I don't see how I design this so that they're all unified.

My ultimate goal is to be able to mixin several concrete pieces like this:

```
 val shopper = new Shopper with IntShopping with Jeep
 val baker = new Baker with IntBaking with SummingRecipe with WoodfireStove with PlasticSpoon
```

(or more specifically:)

```
 val solver = new Solver with GraphColoring with LocalSearch with ColorReduction with RandomChanges
```

Where Solver needs a problem space (GraphColoring) which needs a solver (LocalSearch) which needs a strategy (ColorReduction) which needs a particular way of creating new state (RandomChanges). It feels like this is what abstract types are for, but I can't quite get there.

---

Regarding @mrhobo's question, it's possible that's the correct way to go, and it's how I do it right now. It just doesn't feel as flexible. I currently have:

```
trait Solver[InputData, Solution]

trait LocalSearchSolver[InputData, Solution] extends Solver[InputData, Solution] {
  val firstSolver: SingleSolver[InputData, Solution]
  ...
}

trait GCSolver extends Solver[InputData, Solution]

class GCMaxMinSolver extends GCSolver with LocalSearchSolver[InputData, Solution] {
  override val firstSolver = new GCGreedySolver
}

class GCGreedySolver extends GCSolver with SingleSolver[InputData, Solution]

trait SingleSolver[InputData, Solution] extends Solver[InputData, Solution]
```

First, there seems a lot of repeated "InputData, Solution", and I can't figure out how to mixin the `firstSolver`. LocalSearch needs a helper-solver, but other solvers don't. I tried this:

```
trait LocalSearchSolver[InputData, Solution, FirstSolver <: SingleSolver[InputData, Solution] ] extends Solver[InputData, Solution] {
```

But it complains that it can't resolve FirstSolver for `new FirstSolver`.

---

Ahh, now I think I'm getting somewhere:

```
class GCMaxMinSolver(val firstSolver: GCSolver with SingleSolver[InputData, Solution]) 
  extends GCSolver with LocalSearchSolver[InputData, Solution] {
```

Now the mixin looks like:

```
val solver = new GCMaxMinSolver(new GCGreedySolver)
```

That's not bad, and could be hoisted out into a separate object to capture a full configuration. Maybe this is the right approach.

Comment: how about using generics for the types you want to keep flexible, like Ingredient?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've edited the question with some of my experiences there.